# Attribute Table Print composer

Tags: attribute-table, print-composer

QGIS 2.18.

Problem: I had use group stat plugin in order to sum colums and obtain a value, which I saved in a csv-file. I then joined the csv-file with my original Layer in order to show in my map the summarized values i had obtained. Naturally, my Layer has more Objects than the summarized table, resulting in the repeatedly listing on the 5 unique values within my layer. I would like to be able to show these unique values in the print composer, its not working though. I'm able to show my attribute table, but i can't tell him to only show the unique values. Do you have a solution?